# Stacked numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I am considerably new to Python.I am willing to stack a few 1-d arrays in python and create a 2-d array using that. The arrays which I want to stack are returned from another function. The minimum reproducible code that I have written for this purpose  has been shown below:

```
def fun1(i): # this function returns the array
  return array # This array is a function of i
h0= np.empty(5,dtype=object)
arrays=[h0]
for i in range(4):
 arr=fun1(i)
 arrays.append(arr)

h=np.vstack(arrays)
print (h)
```

The desired output is of the form :

```
[[1 1 1 1 1]
 [2 2 2 2 2]
 [3 3 3 3 3]
 [4 4 4 4 4]]
```

But I get :

```
[[None None None None None]
 [1 1 1 1 1]
 [2 2 2 2 2]
 [3 3 3 3 3]
 [4 4 4 4 4]]
```

I understand that I get the above output because an empty array of `dtype=object` has all elements `None` . But I am not being able to solve the problem. Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why did you use the `h0` at all?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting None because you are creating an empty array with dtype object:

```
h0 = np.empty(5,dtype=object)
```

This line creates an array with *None* elements.

You can remove this line so that it works as you expect:

```
def fun1(i): # this function returns the array
  return array # This array is a function of i
arrays=[]
for i in range(4):
 arr=fun1(i)
 arrays.append(arr)

h = np.vstack(arrays)
print (h)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if np.where(~a.any(axis=1))[0]:
    #do nothing
else:
    #print as you like
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
h = np.vstack([
    fun1(i)
    for i in range(4)
])

print(h)
```

^^ this is assuming that `fun1()` is some proprietary function returning arrays of same length

but if you want a 2D array with equal rows entries and incrementing column-wise like

```
[[1 1 1 1 1]
 [2 2 2 2 2]
 [3 3 3 3 3]
 [4 4 4 4 4]]
```

you can also try a faster method

```
x = np.arange(1,5).reshape([-1,1])
h = np.repeat(x, 5, axis= 1)
```